# How to show element with id and hide other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hide

I've got a list with a few elements and ids:

```
<ul>
<li id="test1">Test1</li>
<li id="test2">Test2</li>
<li id="test3">Test3</li>
</ul>

<div class=test1">Test 1, okay!</div>
<div class=test2">Test 2, okay!</div>
<div class=test3">Test 4, okay!</div>
```

If I'm clicking on an li, the specific div (with the same class) should appear and the other ones should hide. I've tried some javascript but it seems not to work.

```
$('.photo-select li').click(function() {
            var productid = $(this).attr('id');
            $('.productinfo:not(.'+productid+')').hide();
            $('.productinfo:is(.'+productid+')').show();
});
```

Comment: You have duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid. `id` must be unique to each element within the `document`.

Comment: ...and the solution is typically to use classes and/or `data-` attributes instead.

Comment: It does not work, anyway...

Comment: Do the IDs have special characters in them, or are they just alphanumeric? Special characters won't be re-escaped into the selector on their own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you have duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid. `id` must be unique to each element within the `document`. Secondly, you can achieve what you require through the use of common classes and a `data` attribute to specify the relation between the `a` and `div` elements. Try this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="foo" data-rel="test1">Test1</li>
    <li class="foo" data-rel="test2">Test2</li>
    <li class="foo" data-rel="test3">Test3</li>
</ul>

<div class="content" id="test1">Test 1, okay!</div>
<div class="content" id="test2">Test 2, okay!</div>
<div class="content" id="test3">Test 4, okay!</div>
```

```css
.content {
    display: none;
}
```

```js
$('.foo').click(function() {
    $('#' + $(this).data('rel')).show().siblings('div').hide();
})
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/f4xysh3q/)

If preferred you can negate the need for the `data` attributes and `id` and instead relate the elements by their index within their respective containers:

```
<ul>
    <li>Test1</li>
    <li>Test2</li>
    <li>Test3</li>
</ul>

<div id="content-container">
    <div>Test 1, okay!</div>
    <div>Test 2, okay!</div>
    <div>Test 4, okay!</div>
</div>
```

```css
#content-container > div {
    display: none;
}
```

```js
$('li').click(function() {
    $('#content-container').find('div').eq($(this).index()).show().siblings().hide();
})
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/f4xysh3q/1/)

Note that while the second example is shorter, it is arguably less robust. It would depend on how well structured and likely to change your HTML is. Either is a perfectly acceptable solution though.

Comment: At least I have the satisfaction of having Ninja'ed you by 10 seconds :)

Answer (score 0):

Browsers can only see the first occurrence of an ID, as they store them in a fast lookup with only one element against each key value.

Use classes and `data-` attributes to avoid this:

```
<ul>
<li class="clickme" data-target="test1">Test1</li>
<li class="clickme" data-target="test2">Test2</li>
<li class="clickme" data-target="test3">Test3</li>
</ul>

<div id=test1">Test 1, okay!</div>
<div id=test2">Test 2, okay!</div>
<div id=test3">Test 4, okay!</div>
```

and the code becomes:

```
$('.photo-select .clickme').click(function() {
        var productid = $(this).data('target');
        $('.productinfo').not(productid).hide();
        $(productid).show();
});
```

The 3 lines of code can be shortened, but this is intended to be illustrative.

The final issue is hiding the initial states. You can add `style="display:none"` or style them out by default with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost there, just some small adjustments:

```
$('li.photo-select').click(function() {
    var productid = $(this).attr('id');
    $('div.productinfo:not(.' + productid + ')').hide();
    $('div.productinfo.'+productid).show();
});
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t7s53q5c/)